# Hi help me please with this regex, why it does not work?

Tags: c#, regex, url, dns

This is filter for domain, which at first block may be http,https,ftp
and I also dont know, how can i realise special case sensativity without typing every world, i need for example: Http or HTTP, or http but not hTtP that is wrong.
Thanks every body for Help!!!

```
string reg = @"^?((http|https|ftp)\://)(([a-zA-Z]|[а-яА-ЯёЁ])[0-9]\_\.+){3,61}([a-zA-Z]|[а-яА-ЯёЁ]){2,6}$";
```

Comment: What strings are you hoping to match with this?

Comment: I'm curious: in which scenario is `Http` alright, but `hTtP` not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want this pattern:

```
^?((https?|ftp|HTTPS?|FTP)\://)(([a-zа-яё]|[A-ZА-ЯЁ])[0-9]\_\.+){3,61}([a-zа-яё]|[A-ZА-ЯЁ]){2,6}$
```

But if you want title case strings in the just scheme part of the URL:

```
^?(([hH]ttps?|ftp|HTTPS?|FTP)\://)(([a-zа-яё]|[A-ZА-ЯЁ])[0-9]\_\.+){3,61}([a-zа-яё]|[A-ZА-ЯЁ]){2,6}$
```

Or allow title case strings in every part, this will get a little messy:

```
^?(([hH]ttps?|ftp|HTTPS?|FTP)\://)([a-zа-яёA-ZА-ЯЁ]?([a-zа-яё]|[A-ZА-ЯЁ])[0-8])\_\.+){3,61}[a-zа-яёA-ZА-ЯЁ]([a-zа-яё]|[A-ZА-ЯЁ]){1,6}$
```